# React Native App: Fetch Weather And Display it using OpenWeatherMap API

Tags: javascript, react-native, openweathermap, weather-api

I have a React Native app and I need to fetch some weather data(current/min/max temp, condition text, and condition icon) and display it. My code so far (just styling) is shown below:

```js
// Weather Card

...
const TemperatureCardSmall = (props) => {
  var apiKey = API_KEY;
    
  var weather = "Clear";

  return (
    <Card style={{ ...styles.tempCard, ...props.styles }}>
      <View style={styles.topContainer}>
        <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
          <Ionicons
            size={45}
            style={styles.conditionIcon}
            name={weatherConditions[weather].icon}
            color={"#fff"}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.currentContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.currentText}>12&deg;</Text>
        </View>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.bottomContainer}>
        <View style={styles.textContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.conditionText}>
            {weatherConditions[weather].title}
          </Text>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.subtitleText}>H: 13&deg; L: 10&deg;</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Card>
  );
};
...

// WeatherConditions.js

export const weatherConditions = {
  Rain: {
    title: "Rainy",
    icon: "rainy",
  },

  Clear: {
    title: "Sunny",
    icon: "sunny",
  },

  Thunderstorm: {
    title: "Thunderstorm",
    icon: "thunderstorm",
  },

  Clouds: {
    title: "Cloudy",
    icon: "cloudy",
  },

  Drizzle: {
    title: "Drizzle",
    icon: "water",
  },

  Mist: {
    title: "Misty",
    icon: "filter",
  },

  Snow: {
    title: "Snowy",
    icon: "snow",
  },
};
```

I currently get the icons from the second file (WeatherConditions.js). But as of right now, I can't fetch any sort of data, which is why I have hard-coded it into the app myself. Using OpenWeatherMap API, how can I fetch the data? Feel free to ask further questions if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an HTTP client to call an API. [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) is a famous promise-based API client. Also, there are many other alternatives like [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent) so you can choose whichever you feel is easier to implement.
If you are looking for free weather APIs then [this](https://open-meteo.com/en) is one example.

Comment: I don't think you got what I wanted to do. I am already using OpenWeatherMap API, I just don't know how to call it so that I can fetch the data. I would like to look at how I can do that through code submition.

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding on my end, Here is a code example for Axios - https://zetcode.com/javascript/axios/
Let me know if it helps.